# KDE for Windows (7): non-resizable dialogs

Tags: windows-7, kde4, umbrello

the problem: I have to use win7 currently, but I want to use Umbrello UML. Now I have installed the KDE for Windows port and the tool is running. But if there high dialogs poping up or other windows that are not resizeable it could happen that I do not reach the bottom buttons because it is out of scree.

Even if I disabled the window snapping via mouse, I cannot move the window over the top border of the desktop to reach the bottom bar. It is always snapping back to the visible area.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a workaround: http://code.google.com/p/altdrag/ is working great. Now I am able to move the window like I want to.